# android render issue causing delays?

Tags: android, matrix, rendering, delay

I'm developing an Android game and I've got the garbage collection to
the point where it GC's only about once every 5 minutes or so, which I
think is acceptable, for now.

The problem is that, every once in a while, I'll see this message in
the logs:

```
08-29 09:58:46.410 W/copybit ( 1912): stretch_copybit::run_render fail
08-29 09:59:09.000 E/libs3c2drender( 1912): int
S3c2DRender::DoG2D(unsigned int, s3c_img*, s3c_rect*, unsigned int,
s3c_img*, s3c_rect*, int, int)::S3C_G2D_ROTATOR_18176 fail
```

And when this message comes up, my game seems to pause for about
100-200 milliseconds..

I'm currently using a Canvas to draw with, although if my memory is
accurate, I've seen this same error message using Open GL as well.

Here's my code to draw the image object:

```
cachedMatrix.reset();
cachedMatrix.postTranslate(-halfImageWidth, -halfImageHeight);
cachedMatrix.postScale(localScaleX, localScaleY);
cachedMatrix.postTranslate(localOffset.x, localOffset.y);
float degrees = (radiansToDegrees(-rotation) + 360f) % 360f;
cachedMatrix.postRotate(degrees);
cachedMatrix.postTranslate(screenPos.x, screenPos.y);

canvas.drawBitmap(image, cachedMatrix, null);
```

Frankly, I am at a loss as to how to get around this.  This is happening on my Samsung Moment phone.

Has anyone else encountered this issue ?  And found a workaround or
insights into why this is happening ?